# editData is returning an error when clicking on edit, add, buttons

Tags: r

I have reloaded the editData packages and library, I have checked i'm using the most recent version of R 4.2.1 and R Studio 2022.07.1 Build 554

I have googled the error code with no luck solving the problem.

Restarted R and R Studio

I have used this line of code many times without issues so I'm stumped help please.

This is the line of code and returned error message;

```
> comp_data01 <- editData(hood_data)

Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6527
Warning: Error in if: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
  3: shiny::runApp
  2: runGadget
  1: editData
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered much later when using editData with a tibble that my date variable columns were not a date class object.

Once I mutated the variables into a date class object and ran editData to edit a row it no longer crashed.

I successfully edited the row and created a new tibble with the edited row.